# Firebase Admin-SDK

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, firebase

Am working on a project and it includes Firebase backend

https://firebase.google.com/

However, I want to use firebase Backend on a java web application, the problem is they only support node.js for web .
But they have something called Admin-sdk

https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup

Can I use Admin-sdk on Java web application ?
note that I don't want to use JavaScript as backend because then java web app will be useless and I can create it fully by node.js

another thing is that I only want authenticate users, add , update, delete from and upload files to Firebase Database which is supported by admin-sdk

I want to know if it will work or its not recommended or there is another option to in java web ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firebase Admin SDKs allow you to use Firebase products in a trusted environment, such as a server you control, or Cloud Functions. The back-end of a web application is also a trusted environment.

But since you're building a web application, you'll probably (also) want to use some Firebase products directly from the user's browser. In that case you'd use the web SDKs for those products, such as the [Firebase SDK for Cloud Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/start) (to interact with files).

Comment: So you are saying it will work without problems .. but i have to use javascript for uploading files?

Comment: @sultanaljahwary since is the client uploading data or files, then you should use the web sdk which is made in Javascript